# In JS,how to get a obj variable's name

Tags: javascript, variables, object

like this code

```
  var Obj = function () {}
  Obj.prototype.getVarName = function () {
    console.log( someFunction() );
  }
  var obj = new Obj();
  obj.getVarName(); //output "obj";
  var obj1 = new Obj();
  obj1.getVarName(); //output "obj1";
```

and i don't want to do it in this way

```
  var Obj = function (variableName) {
    this.variableName = variableName || "undefined";
  }
  Obj.prototype.getVarName = function () {
    console.log(this.variableName);
  }
  var obj = new Obj('obj');
  obj.getVarName(); //output "obj";
  var obj1 = new Obj('obj1');
  obj1.getVarName(); //output "obj1";
```

someone has any idea to do with this problem,thanks.

p.s：I was doing something in somg incorrect way.so I ask this Unanswered question,thanks all guys.

I bing an event to an DOM elem by a class obj's method ,and this obj has somg child class obj,when trigger the event,this varialbe is point to the dom elem,any I don't know how to recognition which obj trigger this event,so i try this way.

But it's a wrong way!So i try it by some other method.I use the call method to change the this variable,and now i solve my problem.

Comment: if they are global, you can find them under some property on window. if they are local, it's VERY difficult to find them.

Comment: unless this is a purely philosophical question, I suspect the reason you're asking it is that you're confused about how to do something (and doing it in some incorrect way).  Would you be so kind as to explain why this feature is important to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the answer is "it can't be done".

Variable labels aren't meant to be looked at by your code at run-time. They're meant for you, as the program author, to be used at program write-time.

If an Object needs a label that you need to examine and use at run-time you should give it that property to use.

```
someObject.myName = "someObject"; // if that's what you really want
```

Comment: As you say,at first,I doing something in some incorrect way.And I try anyother way to do with it,and got the correct method.

Answer (score 1):

There's simply no relation from an object to the variable holding it as value.

Because there can be more than one variable.

```
var obj = new Obj();
var obj2 = obj;
obj2.getVarName(); // what do you want ?
```

That's one of the basis of the concept of variable in probably all programming languages. You won't change that. if you want your objects to have a name, the solution is to give them a name, not using the variable names.

Comment: I don't know how to explain why i ask this question.But finally,I found it that I was doing something in an incorrect way.Thank's for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

What dystroy and Genia S. said.

Your code smells BAD. Why are you trying to do this?

The way you **don't** want to do it actually looks like the best option, i.e. create an object with a name field.

Comment: Listen to you option,and i fine i just do it in some incorrect way just Genia S say.And I recognize that my code it's so bad,I will try to write code more better then before.Think you.